# How to use makeindex?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I'm having a hard time exporting an index to a pdf file. I can't find any option named `:makeindex` as per [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Generating-an-index.html)

Pasting the lines below to `/tmp/tmp.org` end exporting hence doesn't render any index:

```
*** Curriculum Vitae
#+INDEX: CV
#+INDEX: Application!CV
```

---

init.el excerpt

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
        '("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
            "bibtex %b"
            "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
            "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
          ))
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? It's not clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "an index".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal example to produce an index of terms using LaTeX facilities on the way to PDF (i.e. it won't work for HTML export or anything other than PDF export through LaTeX):

```org
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{makeidx}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \makeindex

* Lorem

Lorem
#+index:lorem
ipsum dolor
#+index: dolor
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
#+index: dolor
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
#+latex: \newpage
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
#+index: dolor
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
#+index: dolor
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
laborum.

#+latex: \printindex
```

This is basically a case where you have to refer to the LaTeX docs for guidance (e.g p.74 and Appendix A of Lamport's book). All that Org mode does is to transcode `#+INDEX: foo` keyword lines into `\index{foo}` LaTeX macro calls. When you include `\usepackage{makeidx}` and `\makeindex` into the preamble of the LaTeX document, then the LaTeX processor will produce a `.idx` file. If you process that `.idx` file through `makeindex` it will produce a `.ind` file that will be used by a subsequent invocation of the LaTeX processor to generate the index. You specify *where* to include the index by adding a `\printindex` command to the LaTeX file (or the equivalent `#+LATEX: \printindex` in your Org mode file as shown above).

It helps if your `org-latex-pdf-process` variable is set up to use something like `latexmk` which automatically calls whatever is necessary, however many times it is necessary. The current default value of this variable is  `("latexmk -f -pdf -%latex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%o %f")` *if you have `latexmk` installed* - in that case, things work very well; if you do *not* have `latexmk` installed you get three invocations of `pdflatex` which does not work at all well in this case, or when bibliographies are involved. You might want to check the setting of `org-latex-compiler` as well: the current default is `pdflatex` I believe, but `xelatex` and `lualatex` do a much better job with Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you link to is for [org publishing](https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing.html), so I assume you are trying to generate an index for an org publishing project.

You need to define your project, and you place the `:makeindex` option in the definition. e.g.:

```lisp
  (setq org-publish-project-alist
        '(("my-project"
           :base-directory "/path/to/my-project/"
           :publishing-function org-latex-publish-to-pdf
           :publishing-directory "/path/to/my/published/project/"
           :makeindex t)))
```

This code goes in your Emacs config file.

Comment: Wasn't aware of publishing. I'm using `C-C C-e l`, yet your suggestion doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you're doing a regular export from org to pdf, then the help page you linked to is irrelevant, and my answer won't help. In that case, you need to do something like the example in @NickD 's answer